# Where has my show class gone

Tags: haskell

I have the following definitions

```
data AST
    = Number Integer
    | Identifier String
    | String String
    -- | Operation BinOp AST AST
    | Query String
    deriving (Show, Eq)

data Tuple = Tuple {cmd :: String, 
                    cid :: AST,
                    argumentList :: [AST],
                    queryList :: [AST]} deriving (Show, Eq)
```

and when I try to print for example cid I get the error

```
No instance for (Show (Tuple -> AST)) arising from a use of `print'
```

that is surprising me since both AST and Tuple are members of the show class. How can I make cid, argumentList and queryList printable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cid` is just a function which is used to access the "cid" field of your Tuple. It is impossible to print it, just as it’s impossible to print `fst`. However, this would be correct:

```
t :: Tuple
t = ...

main = print (cid t)
```

Comment: Is there any way to extract all members from argumentList that are Numbers?

Comment: Do you mean `[i | Number i <- argumentList tuple]`? Or `let isNumber (Number _) = True; isNumber _ = False in filter isNumber (argumentList tuple)`?

Comment: @DanielFischer the first. Thx. Where is the documentation must I look to learn this?

Comment: @JFritsch If you mean learning list comprehensions, there’s a [chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#im-a-list-comprehension) in LYAH and the [rigorous definition](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#list-comprehensions) can be found in Haskell Report.

Answer (score 4):

You can't print `cid`.

You *can* print `cid tuple`, where `tuple` is a value of type `Tuple`.

Your error message

```
No instance for (Show (Tuple -> AST)) arising from a use of `print'
```

indicates that you are trying to print a value of type `Tuple -> AST`. Functions cannot be printed.